# Can the IP imply in its structure where the server of that address is?

Tags: ip

Can the IP imply in its structure where the server of that address is?
this is the original qustion:
Look at the different IP addresses, do you think there is a connection between the IP addresses and the country?
If you found such a connection, write 2 examples here.

i have this qustion in my work:
Look at the different IP addresses, do you think there is a connection between the IP addresses and the country?
If you found such a connection, write 2 examples here.